# Percona Xtradbcluster: Error while getting data from donor node

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, percona, xtradb

I've a problem in joining new node to percona xtradbcluster.

here is my log :

I tested the test_sstuser working on honor without any problem .

but in new nodes I get these errors :

```
2014-05-31 04:01:40 2391 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (02dc9b38-e825-11e3-a67b-4bfddfde0c98): 1 (Operation not permitted)
 at galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:prepare_for_IST():447. IST will be unavailable.
WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Error while getting data from donor node:  exit codes: 1 0 (20140531 04:01:40.934)
WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Cleanup after exit with status:32 (20140531 04:01:40.936)
2014-05-31 04:01:40 2391 [ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 --role 'joiner' --address '192.168.0.2' --auth 'test_sstuser:123456' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' --parent '2391'  '' : 32 (Broken pipe)
2014-05-31 04:01:40 2391 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to read uuid:seqno from joiner script.
2014-05-31 04:01:40 2391 [ERROR] WSREP: SST failed: 32 (Broken pipe)
2014-05-31 04:01:40 2391 [ERROR] Aborting
2014-05-31 04:01:41 2391 [Warning] WSREP: 1.0 (test.host.com): State transfer to 0.0 (master-2.test.net) failed: -32 (Broken pipe)
2014-05-31 04:01:41 2391 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_group.c:gcs_group_handle_join_msg():723: Will never receive state. Need to abort.
```

how can I solve this problem ?

Best regards

Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. The fix is simple, just add the following to my.cnf in the [mysqld] section innodb_log_file_size=48M

(Use whatever size log file you need, 48M is OK for small Dbs)

Then follow the instructions to restart mysql with a new log file size. The basics are (but READ the Manual!) stop mysql remove the ib_logfile* files from /var/lib/mysql restart mysql

Be sure not to be using innodb fast shutdown (read the manual!)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, with another more message:

`WSREP_SST: [ERROR] xtrabackup process ended without creating '/path/to/mysql/xtrabackup_galera_info' (20150108 13:09:23.012)`

The issue was that I was using xtrabackup and not xtrabackup-v2 in my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
wsrep_sst_method                        = xtrabackup
```

Setting it to:

```
wsrep_sst_method                        = xtrabackup-v2
```

fixed the issue.

Some recommend not to set this variable.

Answer (score 1):

We just experienced this error on 1 node out of a 3-node cluster. Manually rsyncing the `/var/lib/mysql` from a healthy node (we stopped that node during the rsync to not change files while syncing) to the broken node was what we needed to make it go again.